# How to display an activity over a different app?

Tags: android, android-activity

I created an Shortcut that opens an Activity. I want that the activity displays over other apps like youtube or so. Currently the app gets minimized and the activity opens. Example: [image]
Google Translate is over my browser

Comment: Can't see the picture in link. Anyway, it's the other app's responsibility to start your activity without `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag. I believe in your example the browser starts Google Translate without that flag.

Comment: Here, I have edited the question but the OP will accept it. I have inserted image